# Query my temporary tables outside my java app

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a java application starting spark (`local[*]`) and exploiting it to read a csv file as a `Dataset<Row>` and to create a temporary view with `createOrReplaceTempView`.

At this point I am able to exploit SQL to query the view inside my application.

What I would like to do, for development and debugging purposes, is to execute queries in an interactive way from outside my application.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark's DeveloperApi - [HiveThriftServer2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala).

> ```
> @DeveloperApi
>   def startWithContext(sqlContext: SQLContext): Unit = {
>     val server = new HiveThriftServer2(sqlContext)
> ```

Only thing you need to do in your application is to get `SQLContext` and use it as follows:

```
HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(sqlContext)
```

This will start hive thrift server (by default on port `10000`) and you can use sql client - e.g. `beeline` for accessing and querying your data in temp tables.

Also you will need to set `--conf spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=true` which allows you to see temp tables. By default it's set to `false` so each connection has it's own session and they dont see others temp tables.

> **"spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession"** - When set to true, Hive Thrift server is running in a single session
>   mode. All the JDBC/ODBC connections share the temporary views, function registries, SQL configuration and the current database.